# Add a new method to a jQuery UI widget

Tags: jquery-ui

The jQuery UI docs give an [example of extending an existing UI widget method](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/#redefining-widgets), like this:

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog,
{
     open: function()
     {
          console.log("open");
          return this._super();
     }
});
```

That works for me using UI 1.12.1, I see the expected log entry when a dialog is opened.

However, using the same technique to recreate the removed .url() method of jQuery UI Tabs does not, throws the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).url is not a function". This is my code:

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs,
{
    url: function (index, url)
    {
        console.log("url");
        $(this.data("uiTabs").anchors[index]).attr("href", url);
        return this;
    }
});
```

What's the difference here, besides the fact that the url() method is being created rather than extended? Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible however I am unsure of that line after the log, i.e. the `.data()` method seems invalid here?

Perhaps you meant this:

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
  url: function(index, url) {
    $(this.anchors[index]).attr("href", url);
  }
});
```

Comment: As I said, I'm getting an error that $(...).url is not a function, so I can't call the code at all. In any case, that data line works in a standalone function.

Comment: You were exactly right Mark. The standalone function worked because it has different scoping, and in the new plugin context, data() doesn't exist as you said. The original error I saw was caused by calling the method incorrectly. I was using the old-style $(...).url(...) syntax, needs to be $(...).tabs('url', ...).